# How can I force a "scroll" in UIScrollViewController by using a button?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uikit

I have a UI that involves a scroll view of 3 view controllers similar to the snapchat layout. However, one of my views is a map and I want the user to be able to scroll and interact fully with the map. 
So I need a button that forces the "scroll" to happen to get the screen back to the other view controller when it is clicked.

I have tried just presenting that view controller and changing the content offset.

```
@objc func goBack() {
    let mainVC = scrollView.mainVC
    self.present(mainVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

---

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width * 3, 
height: self.view.frame.size.height)
scrollView.contentOffset.x = view.frame.width
```

I am using goBack() as the function in my ViewController to cause the scrollView to force scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `scrollRectToVisable` and provide frame, it can be done like this, `width * 3` is changeable depending on the screen location in your scroll view:

```
let frame = scrollView.frame
frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * 3
frame.origin.y = 0
scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(frame, animated: true)
```

But that should get the job done.